# Scroll ListView and TextView Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create a layout composed of :

- textview, as a title
- listview

and all when the user scrolls down/up all the content scrolls together (not only inside the listview)
Any ideas?

Comment: Try for your listview and textview inside a "Scroll View" in your xml..

Comment: yeah i tried, but the listview does not expand.. it shows only the first element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you load the title into the listview, as the top item, and make your activity extend ListActivity?

If you want the title to be formatted differently, you can specify this on the getView() method --

```
if (position == 0) {
   //format title item }
else {
   //format other items
```

Comment: nah i don think this is a clean way to do that!!

Comment: what do you mean, there's not a CLEAN way?

Comment: after comparing some solutions, i think this is the best way to do it. Sorry for my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You can define your textview like this:

```
View textView = ((LayoutInflater)Activity.this.getSystemService(Activity.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.textview_title, null, false);
```

and then add it as a listview header

```
myListView.addHeaderView(textView);
```

If you want to set the selection to be the first list item after the header view you can use

```
myListView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

Comment: at first time, there will be only textview, but what if there is some other widgets.. i want all the view to scroll